# Launch cvlc from the CLI on the secondary screen

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vlc

Under Ubuntu 17.10, I want to lauch vlc or cvlc from the command line in such a way that the video starts immediately in fullscreen mode on the secondary screen (a TV) that is connected by HDMI.

A lot of tricks setting the DISPLAY variable do not (longer?) work, as v.gr.:

```
DISPLAY=:1 cvlc -f video.mp4
DISPLAY=:O.1 cvlc -f video.mp4
```

Using the option

```
cvlc --x11-display :1 -f video.mp4
```

doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found some trick to do it. It is not properly with **cvlc**, but with **vlc**:

```
vlc --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=1 -f video.mp4
```

But I am not 100% satisfied, because if I interrupt the video, the GUI of VLC stays on the secondary screen, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: What about the sound, can you send the sound to the second monitor?

Comment: Thanks I found a way to send the audio to the second tv via HDMI2 using  --alsa-audio-device hw:1,0